# Disable phased updates in 20.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, updates

In Ubuntu 20.04 LTS the software updater says there are no available updates, but `apt list --upgradable` shows packages that can be upgraded. (I ran the command because I had installed something and then apt said I should.) [Update-manager does not show all updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369722/update-manager-does-not-show-all-updates/369769#369769) says updates can be phased and it's possible to disable them. Apparently, there are two preferences, `Update-Manager::Never-Include-Phased-Updates "True";` and `APT::Get::Never-Include-Phased-Updates "True";`. Does that work for Ubuntu 20.04 and will it solve the problem?

```
$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
update-notifier-common/focal-updates,focal-updates 3.192.30.6 all [upgradable from: 3.192.30.5]
update-notifier/focal-updates 3.192.30.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.192.30.5]
```

Comment: @guiverc I meant Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I edited the title.

Comment: I don't quite see how Phased Updates is a "problem". Confusing for a minute or two when first encountered, but not a real problem for most users. Your method of disabling is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Add this string:

```
Update-Manager::Always-Include-Phased-Updates;
APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates;
```

or

```
Update-Manager::Never-Include-Phased-Updates;
```

(A True/False boolean is not needed)

You should be able to add that line to any config file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`. Or create your own: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99-Phased-Updates`

sources:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1246984/34298
- https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/phased-updates-in-apt-in-21-04/20345

Comment: What's the difference between `Update-Manager::Always-Include-Phased-Updates;` and `Update-Manager::Never-Include-Phased-Updates;`? If possible then please provide the source please.