# Package conflicts with another package that is not installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, nala

I am on Ubuntu MATE 22.04. After a `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt list --upgradable` I get the following output:

```
apt-utils/jammy-updates 2.4.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.7]
apt/jammy-updates 2.4.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.7]
libapt-pkg6.0/jammy-updates 2.4.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.7]
```

When I try to upgrade with `sudo apt upgrade`, all 3 packages are kept back.

If I do `sudo nala upgrade` instead (nala is just another frontend for apt that I prefer because it is more informative), it explains why some of the packages are kept back:

```
The following packages were kept back:
apt
└── apt conflicts with apt-transport-https 

libapt-pkg6.0
└── libapt-pkg6.0 (!= 2.4.8) will break libapt-pkg 

Nala was unable to determine why these were held:
  apt-utils
```

I am confused about the reason that apt is being kept back. It says that apt conflicts with apt-transport-https, but as far as I can tell, apt-transport-https is not installed on my system.

Output of dpkg -l apt-transport*:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                Version      Architecture Description
+++-===================-============-============-=================================
un  apt-transport-https <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Output of `apt-cache policy libapt-pkg6.0`:

```
libapt-pkg6.0:
  Installed: 2.4.7
  Candidate: 2.4.8
  Version table:
     2.4.8 500 (phased 40%)
        500 http://mirror.il-jr.kamatera.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.4.7 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.5 500
        500 http://mirror.il-jr.kamatera.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Output of `dpkg -l | grep libapt-pkg`:

```
ii  libapt-pkg-perl                          0.1.40build2                            amd64        Perl interface to libapt-pkg
ii  libapt-pkg6.0:amd64                      2.4.7                                   amd64        package management runtime library
ii  python-apt-common                        2.3.0ubuntu2.1                          all          Python interface to libapt-pkg (locales)
ii  python3-apt                              2.3.0ubuntu2.1                          amd64        Python 3 interface to libapt-pkg
```

I believe that this issue is not related to phased updates for two reasons:

1. From my experience, if packages are held back because of phased updates then nala doesn't specify a reason why they are held back.
2. I added the 99-Phased-Updates file to /etc/apt/apt.conf.d to disable phased updates and the issue persists.

Can someone explain this behavior and how to resolve this?

Comment: what is the output of `dpkg -l apt-transport*` ? Copy the result into your question (**not** in a comment)

Comment: @kanehekili I added the output

Comment: @mikewhatever I am actually aware of the phased updates system, but it seems like the first two packages are held back because of conflicts. Doesn't that mean that they are held back for a reason that is not the phased updates system?

Comment: `apt-cache policy libapt-pkg6.0` and `sudo apt upgrade apt-utils` and `dpkg -l | grep libapt-pkg` please.

Comment: @nobody Added the output to the question.

Comment: where did you get this version for `libapt-pkg6.0`? ` *** 2.4.7 100`` And your config for phased update is not working.

Comment: @nobody I'm not sure where I got this version, is there a way to check? And how do you know that the config for phased update is not working?

Comment: Did you try actually running `apt upgrade` with phased updates disabled? Try `sudo apt -o APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true full-upgrade`.

Comment: `libapt-pkg6.0:
  Installed: 2.4.7
  Candidate: 2.4.8
  Version table:
     2.4.8 500 (phased 40%)
        500 http://mirror.il-jr.kamatera.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages` see it is phased.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like despite the the reasons I had to think the packages were being kept back for some reason other than phased updates, phased updates actually were the cause.

Disabling phased updates using a file in the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ directory as suggested in [What are phased updates, and why does Ubuntu use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them) did not work for me, but running `sudo apt -o APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true full-upgrade` as suggested by @Artur Meinild did install all three packages.

The main confusion here was because nala gave me different reasons to why the packages were being held back. I will report this as a bug.

Comment: Good idea to report it as a bug. Please keep in mind that `nala` is software in a development state (currently in version 0.11.1), while `apt` is a long-time stable software. In the future, maybe trust `apt` more with regards to error messages. I also use `nala`, and find it much more intuitive to use, but I would always use `apt` for troubleshooting. 

Comment: @ArturMeinild Hmm, I never even noticed that nala is in a development state. Anyway, I checked and it looks like recognition of phased updates is a known issue and a requested feature.