# How to force use of stable repositories for 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository

I am concerned that somehow beta/candidate, not stable, 22.04 repositories are being used by 22.04 on my machine. The listing for the relevant repositories is from the command

```
add-apt-repository --list
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main multiverse universe restricted
```

If the above output does indeed indicate that beta/development applications/configurations are being used, how does one issue commands to

1. Ensure that only stable/production versions are to be installed/updated?
2. Force removal/downgrade to stable/production versions if any beta/development versions in fact are in use?

Comment: I see no mention of `jammy-proposed` in your provided list, why are you worried?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

Why are you concerned? You don't have any reason to be. Only stable repositories are enabled by default, which is one of the compelling reasons for companies to use Ubuntu in the first place.

Packages from the official Ubuntu repositories (`distro`, `distro-updates`, `distro-backports` and `distro-security`) are curated and stable releases, often based on the corresponding Debian packages. You can read more about the [package release cycle here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates).

Only if you enable the `distro-proposed` repo, install custom repositories, or install snap packages from the `edge` or `beta` channels, then you may end up with alpha, beta or other developments versions.

*It would be useful if you could state your source of concern. As it stands now, your question mostly is a source of FUD (Fear, Uncertainty, Doubt).*

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.  The name "distro-proposed" should be prominent advertised.   I previously saw some updates "held back" and the packages were not installed because -- I was told -- "held back" meant development but not stable, despite that I thought I had only allowed stable/production repos from Ubuntu.  I no longer saw such updates/upgrades held back, and thus was concerned that such "held backs" hence were being installed.  Again, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: "Held back" could be because of phased updates - there are many topics about this.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them explains "phased updates".  If I understood what I read in the URL, LTS (enterprise, hardened, production, not enthusiast) updates that are "claimed" to be production, not beta, in fact may have significant software defects.  By "phasing", a (small?) fraction of LTS systems are updated (I am not mentioning enthusiast because that is NOT enterprise) effectively to serve as testers, meaning that as with, say MS Windows, "production" really means beta for deployed base to reveal defects.