# Why is LivePatch on Ubuntu 22.04 asking me update the same packages every reboot?

Tags: canonical-livepatch

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 from 20.4 a few weeks back, I see this screen every reboot.

[LivePatch update popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FdrF.png)

Any ideas as to why this is happening?
This did not happen on Ubuntu 20.04.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I realize this is the "system updater", as someone put it. it asks me to update these package even after I update them, every reboot.

Comment: That is just the software updater you are seeing.  You should update those applications, but they may not be ready for updating yet if they are packages for the phased updates.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them

Comment: I update the packages every day, sometimes a few times a day. It might be the bug that the link that you provided talks about. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are phased updates, and why does Ubuntu use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the repositories that I was updating from, I found some lingering 20.04 repositories and "i386" references. It works now, after cleaning all this up.