# How do I handle these delayed GRUB software updates on 22.04.1?

Tags: grub2, updates, update-manager

These bootloader updates have been showing up as unselected for 5-7 days.

[image: bootloader updates]

I tried selecting them so they would install a couple of days ago but the updates program crashed.

Now I'm not sure if I have to select them to get them to install or if they will eventually install on their own.

Do I have to select them?  Or will they eventually install on their own?

### Days Later

Many days later, there is still no clear answer to this, but when I check updates I see the following listed:

[image: updates available]

Additionally, I have no way to know if those listed are related to the original GRUB updates shown in the first snapshot.  It's quite confusing.

However, when I check the User Interface (Software Updates) I don't see any available?  (The unselected ones shown above no longer show up.)

[image: no updates available]

My original question was: Do I have to explicitly choose these updates myself or do they install automatically at some point?
I'm still not sure.

#### 4 Days Later

Today a kernel update showed up and the original GRUB updates showed up in the Software Updates UI list again.

[image: kernel updates with GRUB]

However, they are still unselected.
Even after installing all the other updates they still show up.

[image: kernel updates part 2]

### Some Updates Cannot Be Selected

Finally, there are some updates that you cannot even select.
The OpenOffice updates shown in the next image cannot be selected.
(If you click the checkboxes nothing happens.)
I'm guessing that these will be auto-updated later.

[image: openoffice updates cannot be selected]

Comment: No, it actually doesn't.  I understand these are phased updates, but my question is about when the phased update will be applied.

Comment: Only Canonical can tell you that. The contents of this site are generated by users like you and me. So, the answer to "when" is opinion based. "*Do I vae to select them?*" **No**. "*Or will they eventually install on their own?*" **Eventually Yes**.

Comment: My grub files just updated today 11/11/2022. And had been held for a while. you may need a separate question on how to repair a broken update.

Comment: @oldfred Were those Grub updates selected by default (did you see that the checkboxes were checked) or did they just update automatically?  Just curious about this. thx

Comment: I have a script that both housecleans & updates. So I ran it from the terminal.

Comment: Where are you updating from? Different mirrors have different update times, some a couple of days after Ubuntu's own. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors I am using http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are phased updates, and why does Ubuntu use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them)

Comment: Someone had previously asked me that and that entry doesn't answer this question.  It's about what phased updates are and other things.  As a user, I saw the unchecked items in the Software Updates GUI and had no idea they were called phased updates & even after reading that entry I had no idea how they would be resolved in the Software Updates app.  My answer adds the snapshots and explains when and how they are finally resolved.  Thanks

Comment: @Pilot6 That answers everything but why GRUB updates are kept back for over two weeks when everything else becomes phased in one to two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**5 Days Later : The Definitive Answer**

Today there are numerous updates and now the GRUB bootloader is indeed automatically selected for install.

**Answer** : The update process will actually auto-update these unselected items eventually on its own without the user having to choose them.

[image: GRUB bootloader selected in list]

Comment: I moved the parts you asked to the question.  Thanks