# Ubuntu Server 22.04LTS fresh install has a dependency conflict

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, updates, 22.04

I have recently installed ubuntu server and I have tried to run updates. Here is the output:

```
:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
76 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

and

```
:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for admina:
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [852 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [796 kB]
Fetched 1,980 kB in 3s (777 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
76 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-bin (= 2.06-2ubuntu10) but 2.06-2ubuntu14 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

This might be a simple fix. I've searched around and tried some of the common fixes eg `sudo apt-get install -f` and a few others without any change.

Edit:
Here's the requested output:

```
:~$ apt policy grub-efi-amd64-{signed,bin}
grub-efi-amd64-signed:
  Installed: 1.182~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu10
  Candidate: 1.187.2+2.06-2ubuntu14
  Version table:
     1.187.2+2.06-2ubuntu14 500 (phased 25%)
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.182~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu10 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.180+2.06-2ubuntu7 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
grub-efi-amd64-bin:
  Installed: 2.06-2ubuntu10
  Candidate: 2.06-2ubuntu14
  Version table:
     2.06-2ubuntu14 500 (phased 25%)
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.06-2ubuntu10 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.06-2ubuntu7 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt policy grub-efi-amd64-{signed,bin}` - it looks like the packages involved are undergoing a [phased update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them) right now

Comment: See if this helps: [fixing broken package](https://askubuntu.com/a/1450452/212123)

Answer (score 1):

According to the results of `apt policy grub-efi-amd64-{signed,bin}` the involved packages are currently undergoing a phased update. They are being held back in most cases, but because this is causing a `broken packages` error in your Ubuntu it would be OK to update them anyway by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade `sudo apt-get upgrade | awk 'BEGIN{flag=0} /The following packages have been kept back:/ { flag=1} /^ /{if (flag) print}'`
```

After doing that you should be able to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` without getting an error message.