# Not upgrading distro-info libgpgme11 python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core

Tags: upgrade, updates

while upgrading software for VPS using CLI, it gives following error:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 imagemagick-6-common
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
#
# An OpenSSL vulnerability has recently been fixed with USN-6188-1 & 6119-1:
# CVE-2023-2650: possible DoS translating ASN.1 object identifiers.
# Ensure you have updated the package to its latest version.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
distro-info libgpgme11 python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

Comment: "*An OpenSSL vulnerability has recently been fixed...*" is not an error message.

Comment: "*Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro...*" is not an error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are phased updates, and why does Ubuntu use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them)