# How to list all packages that are in "/var/lib/dpkg/status" state?

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04

On my Ubuntu 22.04, I have some packages that show "/var/lib/dpkg/status" in `apt policy` :

```bash
$ apt policy fonts-noto-color-emoji systemd-hwe-hwdb
fonts-noto-color-emoji:
  Installed: 2.038-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.042-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
     2.042-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500 (phased 10%)
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
 *** 2.038-0ubuntu1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.034-1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
systemd-hwe-hwdb:
  Installed: 249.11.3
  Candidate: 249.11.4
  Version table:
     249.11.4 500 (phased 10%)
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
 *** 249.11.3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$
```

How can I list them all so I can a do a `sudo apt install --reinstall packageName1 packageName2 ...` from the Ubuntu repositories ?

Comment: Trying to reinstall those packages seems wasted effort. Your output clearly shows why they are not updating automatically -- they are phasing.

Comment: @user535733 The re-installation of these 2 packages went perfectly fine fortunately.

Comment: @SebMa yes, but that misses the point of using phased updates. They will be upgraded as the phasing progresses (or not, if the devs find some problem during the phased rollout and pull it back). In any case, those with `/var/lib/dpkg/status` as the source are "local" packages, see dupe on how to list them

Comment: @muru What are `phased updates` ?

Comment: @SebMa see https://askubuntu.com/q/1431940/158442