# Unmet dependencies after Ubuntu 20.04 -> 22.0.4 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, dependencies

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04LTS. After the upgrade, however, I have problems with `apt-get upgrade`, since many upgrades are kept back. Here is the full list:

> base-files cpp language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en
> language-pack-gnome-en-base libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri
> libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers
> mesa-vulkan-drivers python-apt-common python3-apt python3-distupgrade
> ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk unzip

I have followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/602/743263) answer with no solution to the problem. It seems the problem is that there are unmet dependencies.

How do I solve this issue?

**EDIT** Here is the output of `sudo apt-get full-upgrade`:

[image]

Here is the output of `sudo update`

[image]

Here is the output of `sudo apt policy base-files`

[image]

Comment: You've not provided the actual package version details for those packages, just copy/pasted the summary detail, so we're rather limited in what help we can provide. I'd check the package versions mentioned are from official sources, if not you have a source issue (likely 3rd party source caused) that needs exploration.  FYI:  If you've added 3rd party sources, you may need to run a `apt full-upgrade` to fix issues too, as well as other causes that you'll better understand if you read all messages & not just summary detail.

Comment: @user535733 That's the output of `apt-get upgrade`. Which details do you need? I had no error displayed while upgrading: how do I find out what has gone wrong?

Comment: @user535733 see the edit

Comment: Your `apt policy base-files` output shows Phased Updates. See [What are phased updates, and why does Ubuntu use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them)